# Web Performance Error (Internal server error)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing, performance-testing

There is a file hosted on server. When running web performance test in visual studio 2012 with the URL to this file, it is giving
**500 - Internal server error.

There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.**

I have observed the following things:

- The same file URL works outside web test(like firefox and IE).
- The web test runs fine with some other URL like `google.com`.

What can be the possible reasons for this error and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error typically indicates an error within the application. This could be a bug in the application or it could be that the request contains parameters that are not consistent or not expected -- i.e. an invalid request.

If the URL sent is **exactly** the same (be sure ALL the query parameters are the same!) then something else about the request is different between the two. Are any cookies being sent along with the URL when you enter it in the browser?  (clear cookies before pasting the URL into the browser to test)